# MySQL fetching returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I would like to get content from MySQL, based on the URL.
For example, show the entire FAQ when the URL is `/index.php?Name=FAQ`.
How could I solve this one?

```
<?php
require("configish.php");

mysql_connect("$hosty", "$uname", "$paswd") or die ("Cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbnme") or die ("Cannot select database");

$url = $_GET['Name'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE Name='".$url."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $res->Content;
}
?>
```

Oh, before you say so, I'm aware of the `mysql_` functions to be deprecated in PHP 5.5 and higher, but I'm using PHP 5.3.10 at the moment.

Comment: 1) What is the problem? 2) You're open to **SQL INJECTION!!!** 3) "Deprecated" means "please do not use for new things now"; this is regardless of what version of PHP you are using *now*. 4) Don't do `"$var"`, just `$var` will do just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the object notation then you need to call `mysql_fetch_oject()`.

```
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Name']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE Name='".$url."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result) {
    while($res = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        echo $res->Content;
    }
} else {
    trigger_error(mysql_error()); // this silently writes to the log file
    echo 'Page not found';
}
```

Don't close the MySQL connection after the query because you still need the connection to retrieve the result set.

If you must use the `mysql_*` library then be sure to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL Injection. It would be better to switch to [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and use a prepared statement.

Also, `or die(mysql_error())` is really bad practice. You should handle the error properly by testing for a `false` return value from `mysql_query()`.

Comment: This solved my problem, but I can't mark it for 6 more minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require("configish.php");

// DON'T QUOTE VARIABLES, IT'S UNNECESSARY
mysql_connect($hosty, $uname, $paswd) or die ("Cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($dbnme) or die ("Cannot select database");

// ESCAPE YOUR VALUES!!! CAN'T PUT ENOUGH !!! ON THIS!!!!
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Name']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE Name='$url'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// DON'T CLOSE YOUR CONNECTION BEFORE YOU FETCHED YOUR DATA
//mysql_close();

while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // ACCESS AS ARRAY IF YOU'RE FETCHING AS ARRAY
    echo $res['Content'];
}
```

Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/), since you're obviously missing these basics.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($res)` its an array. not an object. and dont use `mysql_*` its outdated. use `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `$url` is not empty.
2. you cannot do `$res->content` in an array (That would be right if `$res` is an object but `$res` is an array.). Use `$res['Content']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require("configish.php");

mysql_connect($hosty, $uname, $paswd) or die ('Cannot connect');
mysql_select_db($dbnme) or die ('Cannot select database');

$url = $_GET['Name'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE Name='".$url."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $res['Content'];
}
?>
```

Use like this. You en-quoted the variables. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code

```
<?php
require("configish.php");

mysql_connect("$hosty", "$uname", "$paswd") or die ("Cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbnme") or die ("Cannot select database");

$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Name']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE Name='".$url."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $res['tableColumnName'];
}    

    mysql_close();

?>
```